# Ionic 4/5 on Angular Prod Build - reduce or package so many JS and svg files

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, build, devops

Prod build of Ionic 4/5 generates hundreds of js and svg files. This is marked as "feature".

It is discussed on their [github](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16391) & [forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-core-using-with-vuejs-without-cdn-creates-100s-of-files/148035/5).

I tried following code changes to route section of their list sample without any success.

1. I was wondering if somehow this generation can be disabled and generate usual 4/5 files of Angular?
2. If not, can this be packaged as part of Angular build?

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomePage } from './home/home.page';
import { ViewMessagePage } from './view-message/view-message.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },

  /*
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule) },
  { path: 'message/:id', loadChildren: () => import('./view-message/view-message.module').then(m => m.ViewMessagePageModule) },
  */

  // above Replaced with components
  { path: 'home', component: HomePage },
  { path: 'message/:id', component: ViewMessagePage },


  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes/*, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }*/)  // <--- Setting commented
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: what are you trying to solve? the chunked js files are a very useful feature as it allows granular lazy loading on as needed basis. Also modern http connection stack allows multi file fetching without issues, so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I am trying to upload these as resources records into Microsoft dynamics 365 PowerApps. Most PowerApps are intranet so even though large, Angular build chunks are perfect. The resources need to uploaded by creating entity record so 180 records for JS & SVG is unmanageable.

I believe, Ionic is limiting itself to internet apps by forcing to accept huge number chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The js files might be impossible to reduce however a lot if these svg files are useless.

I had to create a script to delete unused icons so I can deploy as web app and not have 1200+ icons.
https://gist.github.com/nucklehead/b568dc13d01b18b902c524754a7c9cd4

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It would be great if Ionic team adds some in-built switch.